# How many records can UPSERT add or update in single request in salesforce..?

Tags: update, upsert, record

My question is if i want to insert 20,000 records and i choose to use UPSERT because it contain both insert and update. my data is going to be updated every day. is it true that UPSERT can only create or modify  25 records at a time..?
Does UPSERT have any limitation in creating or modifying any record (like 25 records)..?

Thank you for your solutions and suggestions.

Comment: where are you getting the 25 number as a limit?  Are we talking via REST API or via APEX DML?

Comment: ya REST API. when we use UPSERT method

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm

Comment: REST API composite update will be limited to 25, APEX DML will be 10000

Comment: Is there any link in between REST API and APEX DML..? @cropredy..According to you what is the best solution for this isssue..?. Initial record load will be of thousands of records and there will be a daily update to the records but the record  update will be less . (only limit amount of records will be updated)

Comment: why not use dataloader; or bulk API - these have no limits

Comment: @cropredy For dataloader: we don't have proper file format. and for bulk API : only for the initial load we have large amount of Records but on the second load we will have less records to change. so we don't want to waste bulk API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit will be 10000. This is same for all DML statement in single transaction.

As Per Salesforce docs
[image]

[image]

So you can see that upsert is also counted as DML statement and for DML statement we have limit of 10K records.

You can also take help of [LIMIT Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) getDMLStatements(), getLimitDMLStatements() to find the limit in runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am going to use REST API to send data to salesforce. we are building FUSION risk management app on the top of salesforce. will this soultion works...?

Comment: I am sending you one link please have a look. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm . is it related to UPSERT..?

Comment: @mukky its related to REST and SubSequent calls.

Comment: YES, I want solution for REST. Can you please help me in this..?

Comment: I am going to use REST API @tushar

Comment: @mukky I suggest you go with bulk API

Comment: for bulk API : Only for the initial load we have large amount of Records but on the second load we will have less records to change. so we don't want to waste bulk API.

Comment: @mukky No matter which API you want to use they all are counted in same limit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment thread, it looks like you have constrained yourself to avoid the "bulk"-type data import features in the SFDC Platform. That is, you've ruled out the Bulk API, Data Loader, and presumably, the SOAP API.

This leaves you with a couple of options:

**Custom Apex REST class** (see Trailhead/Apex doc)

- This can take in a POST body of whatever you define (an array of objects to insert). Not too big or heap may blow up or CPU limit may blow up. Ideally 200 objects per POST.
- Then, using Apex DML, you can upsert these and your governor limit will be 10,000 records (across all objects in the transaction)
- Your client system can call this REST endpoint a handful of times until you've done the initial load and then as needed as new records need to be transferred
- You will have to write this code and test it per normal SFDC practice

**OOTB Composite REST API.**

- Covered in the [REST doc here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm)
- Limited to 25 records per REST call
- Your client code creates batches of 25, makes call; then rinse and repeat

**Third party middleware**

- Jitterbit, Boomi, Informatica, Mulesoft, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much sir                                                    .